# Keyboard configuration

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, input-method

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and I have trouble configuring my keyboard. This is driving me crazy...

I have an apple aluminum keyboard, Swiss french layout.

I don't understand how things are handled. I played with:

- language support -> input method system: default / ibus / noe
- input methods
- text entry settings
- setxkbmap

My troubles:

- brackets [ and {: closing elements are not next to the enter key
- backslash cannot be done by ALT + <
- keypad dot prints a comma

Comment: Finally found my way out:
 
    setxkbmap -layout ch,fr -model pc105

sorry for the noise!

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer.  It may help future users with the same problem.

Comment: I wanted first, but as a newcomer, I have to wait 8 hours before answering my own questions. done, now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found my way out:

setxkbmap -layout ch fr -model pc105

sorry for the noise!